# how to add a simple message to a php-gtk statusbar?

Tags: gtk2, php-gtk

I have a simple GtkStatusBar created with glade,and want to add a simple message with the date of the last update of the database (just a simple and plain date).

I don't want to use the whole stacks, context and all the other things that gtk developers put on the statusbar code.

(I could simply use a label but I would like to keep the drag bar).

I'm using Gtk 2.0.1 with php 5.2.6;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/articles/have-a-status-area-using-GtkStatusbar.php

To display a message, we need to first get a message id with GtkStatusbar::get_context_id(), then display the message with GtkStatusbar::push().